# How to get sub string from a string in python using split or regex

Tags: python, regex, split

I have a `str` in python like below. I want extract a substring from it.

```
table='abc_test_01'

number=table.split("_")[1]
```

I am getting `test` as a result.

What I want is everything after the first `_`.

The result I want is `test_01` how can I achieve that.

Comment: `table.partition("_")[2]`

Comment: Or: `table.split('_', 1)[1]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code as already given by many of them

```
table='abc_test_01'
number=table.split("_",1)[1]
```

But the above one may fail in situations when the occurrence is not in the string, then you'll get `IndexError: list index out of range`

For eg.

```
table='abctest01'
number=table.split("_",1)[1]
```

The above one will raise `IndexError`, as the occurrence is not in the string

So the more accurate code for handling this is

```
table.split("_",1)[-1]
```

Therefore -1 will not get any harm because the number of occurrences is already set to one.

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 1):

You could do it like:

```
import re
string = "abc_test_01"

rx = re.compile(r'[^_]*_(.+)')
match = rx.match(string).group(1)
print(match)
```

Or with normal string functions:

```
string = "abc_test_01"

match = '_'.join(string.split('_')[1:])
print(match)
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the substring (all characters after the first occurrence of underscore):

```
number = table[table.index('_')+1:]
# Output: test_01
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

Edit: Thanks to `@valtah`'s comment:

```
table = 'abc_test_01'
#final = "_".join(table.split("_")[1:])
final = table.split("_", 1)[1]
print final
```

Output:

```
'test_01'
```

Also the answer of @valtah in the comment is correct:

```
final = table.partition("_")[2]
print final
```

Will output the same result

Comment: `"_".join(table.split("_")[1:])` makes so many unnecessary operations: 
 splitting, slicing, joining, when all you need is to set `maxsplit` to 1. So `table.split("_", 1)[1]` also works.

Comment: Great answer again! i didn't know that i can do this with `str.split()`. I'll edit my answer. Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 1):

Nobody mentions that the [`split()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=split#str.split) function can have an *maxsplit* argument:

> str.split(sep=None, maxsplit=-1)
>
> return a list of the words in the string, using *sep* as the delimiter string. If *maxsplit* is given, at most *maxsplit* splits are done (thus, the list will have at most *maxsplit*+1 elements).

So the solution is only:

```
table.split('_', 1)[1]
```